# Switching between different platforms

Tags: c#, sqlite, automation

I am writing a test scripts for different platforms in C# using SQLite database for automation. Test script are different for every other platform and I need to write it in same file.I am not able to figure out best way to switch between platforms(platform is a music player from different vendors). Currently I am using global constant for the same but its not the best way to so. 
eg:
Something like

```
bool TestCase1()
 {
    //functionality which is common among all platforms
    if (PlatformA)
    {
        //do this
    }
    else if (PlatformB)
    {
        //do this
    }
    else
    {
        //do this
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Please suggest the best way to do the switching. I am looking for generic way so that in future if new platform comes and having similar functionality then there should not be any need to compile the code.

Comment: Consider using Strategy Pattern http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way would be using an "interface" that you inject using a dependency Injection inversion of control technique.

Out of the box there are several IoC's available depending on the platform you are programming (ASP, UWP..) what they would typically do is at the start register athe interface or instance that does "some thing" and then the application does "that something using a "abstraction" of that code contract. this is normaly an abstract class or an interface. Do you have a requirement at runtime to change aka have both options available, a fall back method?

As you are "unit" testing one could to both tests using a Mocking framework MOQ is one of them that is well dokumented.

if you do integration testing one would/could write 2 tests one for each implementation. Having 2 tests makes it easyer to unterstand what is being tested and hoe "stable" that tested code is.

Hope to have helped